# Access SubReport Lookup Value from Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been breaking my brain all day with this, and I'm starting to really despise Access.  At the root, I want to be able to use a textbox value in a Report to populate another Report textbox by looking up the value from a table. Here's a vanilla version:

- Open Access 2016.  Create Blank Database. Create Table called Table1 with 3 Fields, ID, Product and Spec. Populate with some data.
- Create a Form or Report called Form1 with 2 textboxes.  One textbox is Spec, the other is Product.
- Try to use DLookup to lookup the Spec of the value in the Product text using some variant of the following:

=DLookup("[Spec]", "Table1", "[Product] =" & Forms![Form1]!Product)

It doesn't work, ever.  I've tried so many variations of this in VBA and just using the control source as well, and none of them work.  What am I missing here?  Do I need to setup some kind of relationship between the table and the form?

I've followed examples from these Microsoft non-help sites exactly, and none of them actually work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172176(v=office.11).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/application-dlookup-method-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Product` field has a text data type, so your code should be like this:

```
=DLookUp("[Spec]","Table1","[Product] ='" & [Forms]![Form1]![Product] & "'")
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  When I use this I'm getting a Name? error so far still.  I tried using it in VBA instead and it seems that the error is related to Access can't find the field '|1'.  Any idea what its referring to?

Comment: Ok figured it out - you were right.  This worked:     DLookup("[Table1]![Spec]", "[Table1]", "[Product] ='" & [Forms]![Form1]![ProductBox] & "'")  Thanks